# Magento 2: How can i change the favicon icon in the template with file type: .svg

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, luma-theme

How can i change the favicon icon in the template with file type: .svg

I just started to learn magento, even though I've been looking for resources on the internet to do it, I haven't been able to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried changing the favicon with .ico and .png but only .ico worked in my case. It is also mentioned in dev docs that **Not all browsers support all these formats**.

[image]

Here are the steps which I followed

Step 1:- Create app/design/<Vendor_folder>//Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <link src="Magento_Theme::favicon.ico" rel="icon" sizes="32x32" />
</head>
```

Step 2: Create Magento_Theme/web directory and add you favicon to it.

Result:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through the admin cms:

Content->Design->configuration

[image]

Go to HTML Head

Set Favicon icon

Comment: If it's in the code, how would I fix it? and edit in which file